# Insert MySQL date x days in future and not a weekend

Tags: mysql

I have the following trigger. The goal is to insert a date into the alarms table that is closest to 14 days from NOW() without that date being a weekend. The target code begins with "INSERT INTO alarms " below. I'm stumped. Thanks for any help.

```
  DELIMITER |
    CREATE TRIGGER Invoice_Funnel_AfterUpdate
        AFTER UPDATE ON INVOICE
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF (OLD.status != NEW.status && NEW.status in ("1","5","7")
        THEN
          UPDATE customers
          SET set sales_funnel_status = '5', sales_funnel_status_date = NOW()
          WHERE customerID = OLD.customerID LIMIT 1 

INSERT INTO alarms (username, createdBy, customerID, date_stamp, alert_stamp, minutes_before, active, subject, note,timestamp,funnel,quote,chance)
              VALUES (OLD.username,OLD.username,OLD.customerID, (NOW()+ INTERVAL 14 DAY),(NOW()+ INTERVAL 14 DAY),'15','1','Post-Sales Follow-Up Alarm','Contact this customer for referrals and satisfaction survey',
              NOW(),'0','0.00',NULL)

    END;
    |
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "closest"? If 14 days from now is a sunday, should friday or monday be returned?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Friday or Monday would be OK, but Monday would be technically "closest to" in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WEEKDAY() or DAYOFWEEK() on now() function, 
which will return to you the day of the week on which event occurs.

and if the day is a weekend u can add the number of needed days.

Comment: Thanks @TaTA. That answer got me to thinking and Icame up with a solution.

Answer (score 3):

One sure can come up with some fancy algorithm, it's late for me, so I simply suggest:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL CASE WEEKDAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY) WHEN 5 THEN 13 WHEN 6 THEN 12 END DAY
```

above is for always return friday. Below is for always return Monday:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL CASE WEEKDAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY) WHEN 5 THEN 16 WHEN 6 THEN 15 END DAY
```

and here is always return closest:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL CASE WEEKDAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY) WHEN 5 THEN 13 WHEN 6 THEN 15 END DAY
```

Comment: A simple solution for a fancyPants :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

User TaTa triggered my brain cells with his answer and I came up with this as a final solution. I am posting it as an answer to help future code warriors, but I have accepted TaTa's answer.:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER Invoice_Funnel_AfterUpdate
    AFTER UPDATE ON INVOICE
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (OLD.status != NEW.status && NEW.status in ("1","5","7")
    THEN
      UPDATE customers
      SET set sales_funnel_status = '5', sales_funnel_status_date = NOW()
      WHERE customerID = OLD.customerID LIMIT 1 
      INSERT INTO alarms (username, createdBy, customerID, date_stamp, alert_stamp, minutes_before, active, subject, note,timestamp,funnel,quote,chance)
      VALUES (OLD.username,OLD.username,OLD.customerID, 
      IF(dayname(date(post_date)) = 'Saturday', (NOW()+ INTERVAL 16 DAY), NOW()),
      IF(dayname(date(post_date)) = 'Sunday', (NOW()+ INTERVAL 15 DAY), NOW()),
      IF(dayname(date(alert_stamp)) = 'Saturday', (NOW()+ INTERVAL 16 DAY), NOW()),
      IF(dayname(date(alert_stamp)) = 'Sunday', (NOW()+ INTERVAL 15 DAY), NOW()),
   '15','1','Post-Sales Follow-Up Alarm','Contact this customer for referrals and satisfaction survey',
      NOW(),'0','0.00',NULL)

END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```